# Is the XMP burster range calculated on the server or the client?

Tags: ingress

In the new build 1.18.1, XMP burster range has been heavily reduced. I had already upgraded to it, before finding this out and reading suggestions to stick with the previous version.

I expect that the calculations are done server side, and keeping the previous version would just give animation of a large radius explosion, but no real benefit. Assuming this is true, there would be no advantage in downloading an older apk and downgrading.

However, I haven't done tests or read about any definitive information on this. Hence, my question: is the range determined on the client, and an older version would actually make a difference?

Comment: As a developer, it would make no sense at all to do it in the client, because if it were done in the client side, cheating would be trivial. The user could set the range to whatever they want by modifying the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range and damages are computer on server side. After the update we made some tests that confirm this.

Another proof of server side damage computation is that sometimes, when you're attacking a portal, you still see a last resonator on it but after a "force sync", portal is neutral.